# Designing chess in android

Tags: android

I designed a user interface for a chess game by using buttons in a table layout. For the chess pieces I took the ASCII values and printed on the button as a string value. But I don't know how get that value when a button is clicked. This is the first time I am programming for Android.

```
       <Button android:id="@+id/a8" android:layout_width="36dp" android:layout_height="36dp" android:background="@color/white" android:hint="@string/b_rook" android:textSize="25sp"/>
```

Comment: check out a8.getText(). This may work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the text value of the button, attach the following `OnClickListener` to all of your buttons:

```
OnClickListener myButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String buttonText = ((Button) v).getText();
                            //Do whatever you want with buttonText

        }
    };
```

To assign it for the `Button` instance "myButton":

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonClickListener );
```