# How to get the text written on the button using onclick method in android?

Tags: android, xml

I am designing chess for that i created 64 buttons.For chess pieces i used ascii codes. For each button i included onclick attribute. Now i want the text(ascii value) written on the clicked button.How it is possible.

Comment: have you tried button.getText();?

Comment: What didn't you like about the answer you received when you asked this question [two days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176657/designing-chess-in-android)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the onClick() method, you receive a View argument of the view that was clicked. Simple call getText() on this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button myButton = (Button) v;
    String text = myButton.getText().toString();
}
```

If you already have a reference to the button in question, you can use that too.